# Joining Dataframes Many to One

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, many-to-one

I have two dataframes, one with info about users and the other about items transactions that I'd like to join together.

The users df have a column with last Trans Ref, items have a Trans Ref too, but as each user buys many things there is a many-to-one relationship.

Say I had user `A, B, C` with trans refs `123, 456, 789`

Then I had transactions with references:

```
123-001, 123-002, 123-003, 124-004
456-001,
789-001, 789-002, 789-003
```

I can cut the item number off the ends of my trans refs and match them to users (many-to-one)

How can this be done in a Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Can you produce two sample dfs of each table and the expected output as it's not clear what you're asking. There are a multitude of questions on merging in `pandas` so it would be helpful to mention how this request is atypical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

*Users dataframe*

```
users_df = pd.DataFrame({'UserID':['A','B','C'],'Trans Ref':[123,456,789]})

   Trans Ref UserID
0        123      A
1        456      B
2        789      C
```

*Transaction dataframe*

```
trans_df = pd.DataFrame({'Tran Refs':[['123-001','123-002','123-002','123-004'],
                                      ['456-001'],['789-001','789-002','789-003']],
                         'Trans Description':['Transaction Info 123',
                                              'Transaction Info 456',
                                              'Transaction Info 789']})

                              Tran Refs     Trans Description
0  [123-001, 123-002, 123-002, 123-004]  Transaction Info 123
1                             [456-001]  Transaction Info 456
2           [789-001, 789-002, 789-003]  Transaction Info 789
```

**Reshape trans_df and merge with users_df many to one.**

```
df_out = (trans_df.set_index('Trans Description')['Tran Refs']
        .apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x))
        .stack()
        .str.split('-').str[0]  #trim -00x from trans ref
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='Trans Ref')
        .drop('level_1',axis=1)
        .merge(users_df, on='Trans Ref'))  #join to users_df on Trans Ref
```

Output:

```
      Trans Description  Trans Ref UserID
0  Transaction Info 123        123      A
1  Transaction Info 123        123      A
2  Transaction Info 123        123      A
3  Transaction Info 123        123      A
4  Transaction Info 456        456      B
5  Transaction Info 789        789      C
6  Transaction Info 789        789      C
7  Transaction Info 789        789      C
```